# SuiteScript Exceeded Data Units

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am using SS 1 and a Suitelet to load a list of associated assembly items and then, the user checks which ones to mod. I mod them but I am running up against that limitation of script usage. Well I offloaded this to a restlet and I did the user auth for the Authorization (username password) now I am getting an
"INVALID_HOST", "message" : "Invalid host debugger.sandbox.netsuite.c" message in the response from 'nlapiRequestURL' I am calling the script from a Suitelet, how can it be an invalid host? Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more info to solve the Invalid Host issue, could be caused by something in the code as I noticed the url is incomplete, if you paste it I could be able to help you further.

Taking a step back to what you are actually trying to achieve you can proceed in two ways:

1: Process the user input immediately. (The user would have to wait until the process ends)

2: Schedule a batch job. (This is the recommended option for large operations)

If you decide to go with option 1(Process Immediately) then I suggest setting up a clientside function attached to a button on the form. Additionally you would need to accept POST request in your Suitelet to receive the data and process it. Your clientside function would process the items in a loop and would pass each item to the Suitelet for processing using ajax calls (Dont use `nlapiRequestURL` as it would use governance points). If you want to get fancy you can even add a callback function to your ajax call and display a progress bar so every time one of the records is processed by the Suitelet your progress bar would be updated and at 100% show as "Complete".

If you go for option 2 (Schedule a batch job) then you can pass the data as a parameter to a Scheduled Script using `nlapiScheduleScript(scriptId, deployId, params)`, process the data in a loop and have it send an email to the user at the end. Preferably you would want to use a Map Reduce script but that's on SS 2.0.

Comment: The url was cut it off and just had ellipses (...). The whole url I am using is as follows: https://debugger.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=60&deploy=1 What more information would you need? It does need to be processed right away as their other processes that are going to be chained together. I would like to go with the restlet as it is already written, but just in case we get nowhere with that, you mentioned a Suitelet, are you saying to create one that just processes info, like without an interface?

Comment: So I would use the deployment url of the suitelet and use jQuery to POST to it and alter data that way? If so is there a way to return success/failure messages back to the ajax call? thanks for any help you may give.

Comment: You can use the same Suitelet you are using for the interface, just make sure your form is sent only when the incoming request is GET. To send back a response from the Suitelet just use response.write("Hello world")

Comment: Thanks, I got it working, and it is nice having the control on the client side. It makes the interface a lot nicer. So thanks for all your help